# How to set the chart editor option “Aggregate” in Google Chart API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I want to set the option "Aggregate" (with value max), available in the Google sheet chart editor, through program code with the Google chart API.

[image]

I don't find any information on the Google chart API documentation.

Some help will be appreciated !

Comment: Does this works for you -> On Charts API Reference -> Query Language Reference -> Aggregation Functions (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#aggregation-functions)

Comment: you can also aggregate the data table using the [group()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group) method...

Comment: I have found this option which is not documented : .setOption('applyAggregateData',0)

Comment: Can you share the answer so more people can benefit from it. Also, if there is no documentation on the matter, you can send feedback from the API pages, so they can add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this option which is not documented : `.setOption('applyAggregateData',0)`